# Parabolic Cusp of an Action on the Upper Half Plane

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, differential-geometry

This is a basic definition question. Parabolic bundles are used in certain counting arguments in my research area. I asked my advisor for a reference on these, and he directed me to the paper of Mehta and Seshadri which can be found here:

http://repository.ias.ac.in/20407/1/305.pdf

On page 207 (the 3rd page of the PDF), they introduce the following notation:

[image]

My question is: What is the definition of a parabolic cusp? I would also like to know the motivation behind the name. A reference would be nice, as well. Thank you.

Comment: this looks promising, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/59915/cusp-width-for-an-arbitraty-fuchsian-group  also http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Fuchsian_group and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuchsian_group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think we have a winner, *The Geometry of Discrete Groups* by A. F. Beardon, Springer-Verlag 1983.

From [the second link in comment](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Fuchsian_group), "Let $\Gamma$ be a discrete subgroup of $\operatorname{PSL}(2,\Bbb{R})$, the group of fractional transformations $z\mapsto (az + b)/(cz + d)$; $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb{R}$, $ad - bc = 1.$ For any $z$ in the extended complex plane and any sequence of distinct elements $\gamma_i$ of $\Gamma$ a cluster point of $\{\gamma_i z\}$ is called a limit point of $\Gamma$. If there are 0, 1 or 2 limit points, $\Gamma$ is conjugate to a group of motions of the plane. Otherwise there are infinitely many limit points and $\Gamma$ is called a Fuchsoid group. A Fuchsoid group is a Fuchsian group if it is finitely generated. For a real point $x\in\Bbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ let $\Gamma_x$ be the stabilizer in $\Gamma$ of $x$. The point $x$ is called a **cusp or parabolic cusp** if $\Gamma_x$ is a free cyclic group generated by a parabolic transformation $\neq\{1\}$ (cf. Fractional-linear mapping). The cusps of $\Gamma$ are represented by vertices of a fundamental polygon on the real axis."

I also put the words

parabolic cusp fuchsian group

in Giggle, found a pdf for a very nice 2002 paper by Long and Reid, which expands on Thurston's MO answer.

Comment: Giggle? A genomics search engine?